# Card Game Python, Saving a shuffled deck

Tags: python, save, shuffle

I am writing a program in Python where the user has to guess if the next card in a pack of playing cards is bigger or smaller than the previous card.
I've got the whole program to work except for one function.

I have two ways of playing this game. One way is to shuffle the deck of cards and the other way is to play with an un-shuffled deck of cards (some random order I put them in when making a text file). What I want to do is when the user selects to play with a shuffled deck, the shuffled deck is saved and overwrites the un-shuffled deck's text file.

The cards in the text file are saved as two or three digit numbers.

Each suit is numbered as follows:

> - 1 - Clubs
> - 2 - Diamonds
> - 3 - Hearts
> - 4 - Spades

As far as card numbers go:

> - 1 - Ace
> - 2 - Two
> - ...
> - 11 - Jack
> - 12 - Queen
> - 13 - King

So the **5 of hearts** would be saved as **35**, and the **jack of clubs** would be saved as **110**

Here is my code so far.

This is my attempt at saving:

```
def SaveShuffledDeck(Deck):
    CurrentFile = open('deck.txt', 'w')
    Count = 1

    for Count in range(1,52+1):
        CardtoaddtoFile = str(Deck[Count].Suit) + str(Deck[Count].Rank) + '\n'
        CurrentFile.write(CardtoaddtoFile)

    CurrentFile.close()
```

If you would like to see the rest of the code for the deck, check out [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/8RYez2V5)

Comment: So what's the question? (Which function isn't working? Does it fail with an exception? What happens instead if it doesn't fail outright?)

Comment: The functions work fine. What I want to do (and it does say it in the long paragraph) is to open the deck.txt file using the LoadDeck function, shuffle it with the ShuffleDeck funciton and then once shuffled, resave it as deck.txt

Comment: "I've got the whole program to work except for one function."
"The functions work fine."

So which is it? Not only that, you still haven't shown what is happening as the code is. This site isn't here for others to search through and correct your code. [It's for asking specific questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ubomb agreed. Also, post your attempt so we know you tried. :)

Comment: I am asking a specific question. How do I save my shuffled list to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to give this a good read: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open

```
open('deck.txt', 'w') # will overwrite it
```

And then do something like this...

```
import random
f = open('deck.txt', 'w') # op
l = [i for i in range(1,111)] # list from 1 to 110
random.shuffle(l) # shuffle that list
for i in l:
    f.write(str(i))
    f.write('\n')
```

EDIT: Sorry, did not use your functions. You could modify this though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried your code, but I have run into a small issue, what this does is wipe the text file and fill it with the numbers 1-110, shuffle it and then write it to file. What I need it to do is to take the numbers 1-13 4 times (as there are 4 suits) and reshuffle that and then save it to file

Comment: Just make a different list then. `[11, 12, ..., 113, .... 21, 22, ... 411]` and shuffle that instead :) Also "Jacks are 11" and "1(clubs)" So shouldn't jack of clubs be 111?

Comment: Thanks, and yes Jacks should be 111, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Be sure to mark correct answers and welcome to Stack Overflow!